# Spring Boot mapping action to view(.html) not working

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a spring boot basic application

```
package com.meenakshi.fileupload;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;



@SpringBootApplication
public class Example {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
    }

}
```

My controller is

```
package com.meenakshi.fileupload.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;



@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.print("REDIRECTED BY MEENAKSHI");

        return "index";
    }

}
```

My index.html is a basic html file in src/main/resources/public folder

My pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I do localhost:8080 I expect to redirect to index.html but I am getting Whitelabel Error Page

When I add thymeleaf dependency and add  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" in .html it works

How to resolve it? Also what is the default view resolver in Spring Boot? Do I compulsorily need to use thymeleaf?

Also, do I need to add something to application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can expose your index.html.

The way I like the most is doing the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

}
```

It will automatically grab your index.html and create a default view controller to serve it.

Another way is doing like you did but returning `ModelAndView` like the following but it suit a Thymeleaf/JSP more then a SPA:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class DefaultController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        IndexModel indexModel = new IndexModel();
        return new ModelAndView("index", "index", indexModel);
    }

}
```